# How to disable MUI auto correct date picker when user input the invalid date?

Tags: material-ui, datepicker

I use MuiMeterial date picker and it works nicely, but the issue is when user input the date 02/30/2023 (this date does not exist) manually, it automatically change that to 03/02/2023. since the dates (02/29/2023 and 02/30/2023) does not exist it automatically get corrected by date picker. how to resolve that behavior to not change the date automatically??  thanks.

Comment: The Basic usage [date picker demo](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-picker/#basic-usage) in the MUI documentation does not behave as you described. Entering `02/30/2023` triggers an error state by displaying the text input box with a red outline. Can you please update your question with more detail? Specifically, indicate the version of MUI, and the type (e.g. StaticDatePicker), source (e.g. MUI core, MUI X, Material-UI Pickers), and version of your date picker. Most importantly, please post your code showing date picker properties configurations and the code for its event handlers.